# What is the less.js complete event callback?

Tags: javascript, less

I'm building a simple web application that needs to compile a LESS file into CSS file on the fly.

I want to call a few JavaScript functions after less.js complete the render of style.less file.

I found the following code in a thread, but nothing working for me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/style.less">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less.min.js"></script>
<script>
less.hasFinished.then(
    function() {
        console.log('completed');
    }
);
</script>
```

Also tried few other things:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/style.less">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less.min.js"></script>
<script>
less = {
    postProcessor: function(css) {
        console.log('complete');
    }
};
</script>
```

Is there any less.onComplete() callback function or something similar??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try pageLoadFinished

```
<script>
less.pageLoadFinished.then(
    function() {
        console.log('completed');
    }
);
</script>
```