How to get HTMLElement property defined in Less with JavaScript?
When I’m trying to get element properties (for example “max-block-size”) using getComputedStyle in JavaScript I get “none”. But when I look into computed properties in dev-tools I can see they have real values. I work with styles using Less. When I convert Less to CSS my script works fine.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>getComputedStyle test</title> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
        <script>
            less = {
                env: 'development',
            };
        </script>
        <script src="less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            less.watch();
        </script>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" /> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="element">some text</div>
    </body>
    <script defer>
        const someElement = document.getElementById('element');
        const styles = getComputedStyle(someElement);
        const maxBlockSize = styles.getPropertyValue('max-block-size');
        console.log(maxBlockSize);
    </script>
</html>

styles.less:
#element {
    outline-style: solid;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    max-inline-size: 10rem;
    max-block-size: 5rem;
}

In case script.js starts running before less finished compiling I’ve tried to add
function sleep(sleepDuration){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* Do nothing */ }
}
sleep(1000);

after beginnig of script.js but it makes no difference.
PS. I use VSC + Live Preview
PPS. github

I presume because less is compiled into css, and css does not know that value?

Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the [<>] toolbar button); here's how to do one. Less isn't supported, but since Less compiles to CSS, you can just include the compiled version. Fundamentally, if the element with id="element" has the max-block-size property applied to it, that code will work. If it's not working, then the property isn't being applied to that element.

When I use CSS compiled from Less it works fine.  It doesn't work only when I use Less.  Despite the fact that I can see right value in dev-tools. I've already added link to github with code

The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be in your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] in the question. More: How do I ask a good question? and Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

defer doesn't guarantee to run after less finish compiling, maybe this is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617553/what-is-the-less-js-complete-event-callback
